# NestedScrollView not saving fragment scroll stated when navigated back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-nestedscrollview, android-architecture-navigation

My App uses a single activity architecture which has a NestedScrollView in the activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/app_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My issue is that that when I scroll a fragment, then navigate to another, then go back, the scroll position is reset. I've seen another answer which stated that adding IDs to the layouts should fix the issue, but it hasn't for me. Also, interestingly, the scroll position saves fine on configuration change.

I'm using NavigationComponents, could this be related? [Here's a sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QBFrXmWgCdmW3tFijp9Kuaq9qUfsKaZC/view?usp=sharing) that reproduces the issue (based on Google's NavigationAdvancedSample)

Comment: If you are injecting fragment to Framelayout i don't think you can save scroll state after unselect

Comment: You should not wrap your container with a NestedScrollView but have it in each Fragment, if needed

Answer (score 1):

NestedScrollView has wrapped the Navigation Container in the activity_main layout. So it is the activity that saves the scroll state. There are 3 fragments. Home fragment has fixed height, Leaderboard and Register fragments are scrolling. When you scroll in the Leaderboard or Register and switch to the other one the scroll state does not change(since both can scroll to roughly the same height) but if you switch to home fragment scroll state resets because it has fixed height(size of the screen). Replacing NestedScrollView with the ScrollView didn't change anything as I examined it.
I think the right design is to wrap each fragment with NestedScrollView and set and get scroll state for each fragment.
Navigation component does not add the fragment to the activity state but replace it. So fragments get recreated after by switching between them. So you see scroll state is being reset. You can check it yourself by putting some log in the onCreateView of first fragment and see the log appears twice.

Comment: It works without NestedScrollview though, i.e. if I put a scrollview in the fragment instead. Is that because the state is saved at the Fragment level, and NestedScrollview only  works onConfigurationChanged because it's saving at the Activity level?

Comment: I didn't think it would work either way. Let me check the sample code closely first.